# Nested devise form not linking models

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms, google-places-api

I'm trying to create a new location and a devise user in the same form and link them. The user and the location are created, but the location_id is not saving to the user. There is a location_id column in the user table.

My form

```
<% resource.build_location %>
<%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form-vertical' }) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>
 <!-- capture location details hidden values -->
  <%= f.fields_for :location do |location_form| %>
  <%= location_form.text_field :name, :name => "name", :type => "hidden" %>
  <%= location_form.text_field :street_address, :name => "formatted_address", :type => "hidden" %>
  <%= location_form.text_field :lat, :name => "lat", :type => "hidden" %>
  <%= location_form.text_field :long, :name => "lng", :type => "hidden" %>
<% end %>
 <!-- devise user authenticate --> 
  <%= f.input :name, :autofocus => true %> 
  <%= f.input :email, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password, :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :required => true %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Sign up', :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Location model

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :lat, :long, :name, :street_address
  attr_accessible :user_attributes
end
```

Location controller

```
def new
    @location = Location.new
    @location.user.build
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @location }
    end
  end

  # GET /locations/1/edit
  def edit
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /locations
  # POST /locations.json
  def create
    @location = @user.location.build(params[:location])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to @location, notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @location, status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :location, :location_id, :location_attributes
end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    authorize! :index, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @users = User.all
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user], :as => :admin)
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
    end
  end

  def destroy
    authorize! :destroy, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    unless user == current_user
      user.destroy
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User deleted."
    else
      redirect_to users_path, :notice => "Can't delete yourself."
    end
  end
end
```

No errors when creating the user, just getting a location_id="nil" when creating the user. I can access the location and a location_id is created but not linked to the user. Any ideas on how to save the location_id to the user?

I am populating the location info with json returned from a google location api autocomplete and assigning to an element with name="". It seems that everything works fine when I manually enter location info, but fails when the fields are populated from the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you do not need `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on both models, only the one that has the `has_many` association. Also, it looks like the pluralization is wrong in the Location model for users attributes

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :allow_destroy => true
  attr_accessible :lat, :long, :name, :street_address
  attr_accessible :users_attributes # <- This should be plural
end
```

Remove the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location # <- This should be removed
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :location, :location_id # Also remove location_atributes
end
```

Also, this line

```
@location = @user.location.build(params[:location])
```

Should be

```
@location = Location.new(params[:location)
```

since the way your models are setup now a location has a user so you do not need to build a location from a user. That being said, I would recommend you create the association in the opposite direction where a user has_many locations, but this of course may be contrary to your function so take it with a grain of salt :).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Thanks Jason, the problem is if I remove accepts_nested_attributes_for in the user model, I get this error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in DeviseInvitable::RegistrationsController#create

Location(#70224765161800) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#70224763369340)

Comment: There may be a problem with having the `UsersController`. Since you are using devise you should not need one at all actually and if you want to override the functionality devise provides you would have to override their controller itself. See this for reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers . You may also want to remove `:location` and `location_attributes` from the user model if you did not.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll take a look at that. I'm sure there are better ways of doing this although I'm still a little confused as to why it works when I manually enter data into the text_field but doesn't work when that same text_field receives json text.